# Generic DAL Architechture

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, data-access-layer

We currently have clients storing data in multiple data sources (MS SQL, Oracle, MS Access, Web Services, etc.).

We have created a framework to handle majority scenarios for MS SQL, Oracle, Access, however some clients are reluctant to provide direct DB access and hence give out only Web Services.

I am unable to come up with a generic solution to handle the 5% problem at hands to create something for the Web Services as the data source, along with others.

Can someone help me how to handle this kind of scenario.

-Naga

Comment: What do you mean by `generic solution`? Best approach is provide direct access to upper layer DAL (through WCF/Web services) which will access lower layer DAL (DB).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I shall try and give you more input of what i am looking for.

If i have 6 clients, each one of them is using different ways to store data i.e. MSSQL, Oracle, Web services etc. we can write a generic DAL Layer to cover SqlClinet, OleDb, ODBC, however the shortcoming is with when we encounter a Web Service. How do we create a DAL for a web service. Hit the DAl for web service and get data to show in UI.

Answer (score 3):

Treat your Web Service data source as no different than MS SQL or Oracle Data source. It is merely one additional concrete data store. Follow a pattern like this:

```
public interface IRepository
{
 List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees();
}
```

here EmployeeModel is a simple C# class, and not tied to Oracle or MS SQL or your web service.

```
public class SqlRepository : IRepository
{
  public List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees()
  {
   // get it from SQL using ADO.NET or Linq2Sql
   // transform into EmployeeModel using Automapper/manual and return.
  }
}

public class WebServiceRepository : IRepository
{
  private readonly ProxyClient _proxy; // or helper

  public List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees()
  {
   // get it from the ASMX using Proxy Helpers with return type as data contracts.
   // transform the data contracts into EmployeeModel using Automapper/manual and return.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the options is to use a Repository Pattern. Have a look at Repository pattern example at this: http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried Repository, it solved the 95% problem for me, but the problem is the 5% where the data source is a Web Service with an end point, and in general we have to customize code to handle n different web service end points, we are now trying to come up with a solution to create a common DAL for Web Service end points and get data. 

I might have missed a point. can you please elaborate more on how can i use Repository for Web Service as a data source.